# "Open systems" version of Stone's Theorem for one-parameter groups of quantum operations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics, semigroups-of-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, which we interpret as a space of quantum states.

- If $U(t):H\to H$ is a unitary **norm-continuous** one-parameter group with $U(0)=I$, (essentially) *Cauchy's functional equation* says it has the form $$U(t)=e^{itA}$$ for some **bounded** self-adjoint Hamiltonian $A$.
- If $U(t):H\to H$ is a unitary **strongly-continuous** one-parameter group with $U(0)=I$, *Stone's theorem* says it has the form $$U(t)=e^{itA}$$ for some **unbounded** self-adjoint Hamiltonian $A$.

Now let $\mathcal{S}_1$ be the set of trace-class operators of trace $1$ on $H$, which we interpret as states in an open quantum system.

- If $\mathcal{T}(t):\mathcal{S}_1\to\mathcal{S}_1$ is a trace-preserving completely positive **norm-continuous** one-parameter group with $\mathcal{T}(0)=I$, *Lindblad's theorem* says it has the form $$\mathcal{T}(t)=e^{t\mathcal{L}}$$ where $$\mathcal{L}(\rho)=-i[A,\rho]+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}L_k\rho L_k^*+L_k^*L_k\rho$$ is a Lindbladian with **bounded** $A$, $L_k$ where $A$ is self-adjoint and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}L_k^*L_k$ is strongly summable.

My question is:

**What can we say in this case when $\mathcal{T}(t)$ is only strongly continuous?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been generalized by Brian Davies to the general case, the article is

Davies, E.B.: Quantum dynamical semigroups and the neutron diffusion equation. Rep. Math.
Phys. 11(2), 169–188 (1977)

A more modern introduction are chapters 5-7 in this book

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-stochastics/0E5897239F5430E41858ACB936DC4386